# Make .scrollTop work on all screen sizes (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollview

I'm trying to append a tab into my sites header and then **change the text content on scroll** so that the text content of the div matches the section on the page. Even though I'm new to JS I actually have this working with the following code:

**JS:**

```
<script>
jQuery( ".menu-column" ).append( "<p>ABOUT</p>" );
</script>
```

-

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop()>530)
     {
        jQuery('.menu-column p').html("ABOUT");
     }
 });
});
</script>
```

-

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop()>1450)
     {
        jQuery('.menu-column p').html("CS17");
     }
 });
});
</script>
```

-

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop()>2300)
     {
        jQuery('.menu-column p').html("ABYF");
     }
 });
});
</script>
```

-

***Note:*** I am aware that separating sections of JS code like this is not the best way to include JS in a page.

-

**CSS:**

```
.menu-column p {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #a7a7a7;
    transition: 0.3s all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s all;
    -o-transition: 0.3s all;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s all;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.menu-column p {
    display: none!important;
}
}

.menu-items-blocks {
    float: right!important;
}

.menu-bar {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

**My Issue:**

This works perfectly on 15" Macbook Pro (designed on this device) but when I resize the browser even slightly, all of my scroll positions are 'destroyed' (i.e out of line) - I presume this is because I need some form of variable parameter or maybe this just isn't the correct way of achieving this functionality.

I've tried to adapt other answers but I can't get anything to work, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: in this case it would make far more sense to select the element you want to scroll to, then use it's `offset().top`. Then you can get rid of all the difference `scroll()` handlers you have and use a single one

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the direction, I'm looking into this option now

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element